# How to fetch outlook contacts using rest API

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I'm very new to outlook plugin development .For my addon, I need to get all the contacts from the current outlook account. I tried with the following code :

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result) {
                if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                    var accessToken = result.value;
                    console.log("access token", accessToken);
                    getCurrentItem(accessToken);
                } else {
                    // Handle the error.
                }
});
 function getCurrentItem(accessToken) {

        var getcontacts = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
            '/v2.0/me/contacts';
        console.log(getcontacts);
        $.ajax({
            url: getcontacts,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
        }).done(function (item) {
            console.log(item);
      }).fail(function (error) {
                    // Handle error.
                });
    }
```

When I used this js file in my outlook addon and consoled it, ends with 403 forbidden error. How to use this? Am I leading somewhere wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for the question.

The problem is , not given permission in my manifest xml file :

```
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```